# coreaudiod and launchd are taking up 80% and 40% processor respectively

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, macos, launchd

I've just upgraded from mavericks to yosemite, the download was sluggish but eventually worked so I don't think any of the files were corrupted. There was no hitch with the installation as far as I know either. All I know is that when I woke up after leaving my MacBook Pro (15 inch, mid-2010) its fan was spinning out of control at the login screen.

When I restarted and looked at the activity monitor I saw that core audio and launchd were the culprits. I've tried the following to fix my problem:

- Clearing the PRAM.
- Clearing the SMC.
- Deleting the plist for the audio preference pane.
- Verifying disk permissions.
- Repairing disk permissions.

Additional info:
I've run etreCheck a few times and have fixed most of the things it pointed out, all that is left is:

System launch daemons with problems :
    [fail]  com.apple.systemstatsd.plist

Launch daemons with problems :
    [invalid?]  com.adobe.SwitchBoard.plist Aide

I've searched and haven't found any answers that worked yet.
Anything else I can do apart from a reinstall?

Also I've noticed that bluetooth can't be turned off anymore although it doesn't actually seem to be on, any fixes for that would be appreciated too.

Comment: since as you say there were many install hick-ups how about cmd-r to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the exact same issue after restarting. I had previously unloaded a bunch of services.

The bluetooth issue was due to unloading the bluetooth service, but I had a bluetooth mouse plugged in via USB, I guess there was some override in the IO or something.

Loading the service again fixed the issue.

> sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist

The core audio issue seems to have been fixed by loading the video assistant again

> sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.cmio.IIDCVideoAssistant.plist

Hope this helps someone as there shouldn't be the need for a full system restore because of one or two service issues.

Comment: This solved it for me, greatly appreciated!